# Can i use more than one class with same names in same package in java?

Tags: java, package

I need to use two same named class in the same package.can i do it? like

```
package MyPackage;
class pkg{

}

class pkg{

}
```

Is it correct?

Comment: Did you try it? If you did what was the result?

Comment: Why do you want to do such a thing in the first place? Now when I ddefine a variable `pkg pkgVar;`  which one will you give to me? If you can answer that question, then you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

You should learn to try these things yourself, or read the language specification.

The short answer is no, you can't do that.